# Select Spring bean according to enum param

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns

In my Spring Boot app I have a notion of `Stage` and `StageProcessor` which processes the `Stage`. `Stage` has a `StageType` enum property. I have different implementations of `StageProcessor` interface, and these implementations are Spring beans. Now, I have another Spring bean, `WorkflowProcessor`, which needs to invoke appropriate `StageProcessor` depending on `StageType` of the `Stage`. So far I have come up with the following:

```
@Service
public class StageConfig {
    @Autowired
    private StageProcessorA stageProcessorA;
    @Autowired
    private StageProcessorB stageProcessorB;

    public StageProcessor getProcessor(Stage stage) {
        switch(stage.getType()) {
            case A:
                return stageProcessorA;
                break;
            case B:
                return stageProcessorB;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder if I am missing any design pattern, or Spring mechanism. Any ideas of a better design?

Comment: Well what I would do is to use an ApplicationContextAware and then return the right object by getBean method

Comment: Is Stage an interface? Is it a bean? Is there only one? What determines whether it will be A or B?

Comment: Stage is neither an interface nor a bean. It's an entity. StageType determines which processor to use.

Comment: You misunderstood. What determines whether `stage.getType()` will be A or B?

Comment: It's just business data, persisted to the DB earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is totally based on @chrylis idea just there's no need for the processors to change their API for this, you can just do it with an annotation. Also, there's the case when you have multiple processors for one type.

```
interface StageProcessor {
    OutputType process(Stage stage);
}

@Component
@Processes(StageType.A)
class StageProcessorA implements StageProcessor{
      OutputType process(Stage stage){
        //validate stage is StageType.A
      }
}

@interface Processes{
    StageType type;
    StageType getType(){
        return type;
    }
}

@Component
@Processes(StageType.B)
class StageProcessorB implements StageProcessor{

}

@Service
class StageProcessors {
    Map<StageType, List<StageProcessor>> stageProcessors;

    StageProcessors(Collection<StageProcessor> processors) {
        Map<StageType, List<StageProcessor>> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (StageProcessor processor : processors) {
            StageType stageType = processor.getClass().getAnnotation(Processes.class).getType();
            map.computeIfAbsent(stageType, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(processor);
        }
        stageProcessors = map;
        assert stageProcessors.size() == expectedNumberOfProcessors;
    }

    List<StageProcessor> getProcessors(StageType stage) {
        return stageProcessors.get(stage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends a bit on the specifics of your case. In many instances, stages aren't actually hard-coded as in an enum but configurable for various systems. Additionally, the more potential stages you have, the more it pays off to have a slightly more verbose setup but avoid repetition.

In general, I would recommend Spring's resolver pattern here. Code looks something like this, where `KeyType` is usually an enum or a string. The general idea is that each implementation tells you what sorts of things (stages, types, parameters, etc.) it can handle, and then you look up the match. (A variant where there's not a direct mapping lookup is to have a `boolean canHandle(something)` and iterate until you find one.)

```
interface StageProcessor {
    OutputType process(Stage stage);
    KeyType stageKey();
}

@Service
class StageProcessors {
    Map<KeyType, StageProcessor> stageProcessors;

    StageProcessors(Collection<StageProcessor> processors) {
        stageProcessors = processors.stream().collect(groupingBy(StageProcessor::stageKey));
        assert stageProcessors.size() == expectedNumberOfProcessors;
    }

    StageProcessor getProcessor(KeyType stage) {
        // although usually your service would take care of dispatching directly
        return stageProcessors.get(stage);
    }
}
```

(And as a note: [Avoid field injection.](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/field-dependency-injection-considered-harmful/))

Comment: That's definitely cleaner design. I will use it, complemented by @GabiM 's ideas. As for field injection, that's just for cleaner prototype code, I will stick to constructor injection in real code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a more straightforward solution: if the relationship between `StageType` and `StageProcessor` is one-to-one or many-to-one, you can directly use a `Map<String, StageProcessor>` in your class for Spring to inject the components, as long as on your `StageProcessor` Spring classes you specify the `value` attribute in the `@Component` annotation.

For example:

```
@Component(value = "StageTypeA")
public class StageProcessorA{}

@Component(value = "StageTypeB")
public class StageProcessorB{}
```

Then you can just retrieve the required bean from the `Map` by calling `get()`.